# Why is $k-\{0\}$ not a closed in $k$ in the zariski topology?($k$ algebraically closed)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

**Why is $k-\{0\}$ not a closed in $k$ in the zariski topology?($k$ algebraically closed)**

I am trying to prove that if $h:X\to Y$ is a morphism of varieties, then $h(X)$ is not necessarily a subvariety of $Y$, for this I am taking $X=V(xy-1)$ and $Y=k$ ($k$ algebraically closed) to thus have a morphism $h:V(xy-1)\to k$, given by $h(x,1/x)=x$. In this case $h(X)$ would be $k-\{0\}$, but I don't know how to prove that this is not a subvariety of $k$, could someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: So the affine variety corresponding to $k-\{0\}$ is $V(xy-1) \subset \Bbb{A}^2$, you need to add variables/dimensions to remove closed subsets of an irreducible algebraic set. Also to each subset $U$ you should think to the corresponding ring of rational functions regular on $U$, here $k[x,x^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no polynomial over $k$ which has roots at all nonzero points but not at $0$ (as $k$ is infinite).

Answer (score 3):

The only polynomial in one variable that has infinitely many roots is the zero polynomial, but $V(0) = k$ (algebraically closed fields cannot be finite).